# Fragment's root view inflation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment x in whose `onCreateView()` a view is inflated and returned.

Now there are two branches in my code, depending on a boolean in my fragment's arguments I'll either directly manipulate the child views of the fragment or I'll rely on an `AsyncTask#onPostExecute` to do so.

What I noticed was I had accidentally tried to re-inflate the fragment's root view, though it didn't give me any error I couldn't change the values of the view anymore.

Removing the statement which did the re-inflation solves the problem, but I'd like to know why is it that we can't re-inflate a fragment's root view and work with its children as compared to Activity's `setContentView()` or if we can if we can then what is the proper way?

Comment: can you also share the code with reinflating the view and how you try to change the earlier view's components..

Comment: i used `getView()` to get a reference to the root view then the usual `findViewById()`